# Поворот изображения в canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Есть функция поворота изображения в canvas:

```
const rotate = async (base64, angle, color) => {
  const img = new Image()
  img.setAttribute('src', base64)
  await (() => { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { img.onload = function() { resolve() } }) })()
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
  canvas.width = img.width
  canvas.height = img.height
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
  ctx.fillStyle = color
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
  ctx.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2)
  ctx.rotate(angle * Math.PI/180);
  ctx.drawImage(img,-canvas.width/2,-canvas.height/2);
  return canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
}
```

Работает в целом хорошо, только обрезает края повернутого изображения, например:
[image: источник]

[image: поворот]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли это как-то исправить? Вероятно нужно как-то высчитывать новую высоту/ширину canvas'a, но я не знаю формулы

Comment: ширина = старой высоте, высота = старой ширине

Comment: ну углы могут быть не только прямые. например 1-89 градусов

Comment: добавил 3 картинку для ясности

Answer (score 5):

Описывающий прямоугольник (bounding box) после поворота исходного прямоугольника имеет размеры:

```
New_Height = Old_Width * Abs(Sin(Fi)) + Old_Height * Abs(Cos(Fi))
New_Width = Old_Width * Abs(Cos(Fi)) + Old_Height * Abs(Sin(Fi))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Ивашка Вопрос решён?